# Proving radius of injectivity goes to zero if volume goes to zero

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ be an odd number. Prove there exists a sequence of compact manifolds, $M_k, k \in \mathbb{N}$, all with the same dimension $n_0$ and the same constant sectional curvature $K_{M_k} \equiv 1$ whose volume satisfies $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \operatorname{Vol}(M_k) = 0$$ Conclude that the radius of injectivity also goes to zero, that is, $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \to \infty}} i(M_k) = 0$.

Since $n_0 = 2m - 1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we can consider the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{2m-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n} = \mathbb{C}^n$ and the quotient manifold $\displaystyle{\mathbb{S}^{2m-1} \over \mathbb{Z}_p}$ (a lens space). It's straightforward to show the volume of this quotient is the volume of the sphere over $p$, so letting $p \to \infty$ we get the desired sequence of manifolds.

But how can we conclude the injectivity radius also goes to zero? I think maybe we could show that $i(M_k) = \dfrac{\pi}{k}$, but I haven't been able to prove this. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Prove that, if the sectional curvature is 1, a lower bound on the injectivity radius implies a lower bound on the volume of the manifold by looking at a geodesic ball of radius equal to, say, half the injectivity radius.